# Sublime text plugins operate irrespective of the file type

Tags: plugins, sublimetext2

I am new to Sublime text. I have been installing a lot of plugins lately.

One thing that I realized is that all the plugins if assigned a keyboard shortcut would perform their operations irrespective of the type of file type.

For example: if I have a plugin such as HTML tidy and if i have a keyboard shortcut say CTRL+K. Now if I open a .js file and press CTRL+K the HTML Tidy plugin somehow ends up executing.

Is this the expected behavior or have I configured something incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

That's the behavior defined by the implementation of the plugin and the associated key binding. I would recommend creating an issue or making a pull request for that plugin where the file type is checked. They can also add a context to their keybindings to only run under a specific scope. You can create user keybindings with a context to run the proper command. But understand that if it does not match a context for your keybinding, it will fall back to whatever the plugin is defined as. Let me know if I can clarify anything.